# Another appication is get installed on running my project

Tags: android

i have developed application while running my application another application **ContactManager** is also get installed.

When i am removing **ContactManager** application then my application won't run and gives me a this two errors

- Project 'SipChat' is missing required Java project: 'ContactManager' sipdroid-read-only Build path Build Path Problem
- The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

I have Cleaned my project and i have checked in my files but i didn't find any import which is related to ContactManager

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: can you specify your package name..

Comment: yeah its **org.sipdroid.sipua**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that project attached under project properties -> java Build path ->project(required projects on build path). Remove that project.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have Build Problems,

Go to project properties -> java Build path -> You will find an error in Source option, Remove it and try to Clean your project and then Build it again.

Other thing is the package you have specified may conflict so try to give other package name.

Hope this helps.